# Launchd is not working

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I am having troubles making a Launchd script. It is fairly simple, all it needs to do is launch an application - the location is: `/Library/Desktop Pictures/wallpaper`

I've loaded the file using terminal, and terminal gives no errors but the script does not execute. I need the script to execute every 1 hour.

The plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>wallpaper.restart</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/Library/Desktop Pictures/wallpaper.wallpaperapp.app</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>1</integer>

       </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please Help.

Thanks,
Devansh

**EDIT:**

Below is the next better version of the above code, but still not much luck :(

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AfterInitialDemand</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.plisterine.backgroundchanger</string>
    <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/Library/Desktop Pictures/wallpaper/wallpaper.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
     <integer>3600</integer>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This looks suspicious: `<string>/Library/Desktop Pictures/wallpaper.wallpaperapp.app</string>`  Are you certain it is correct?

Comment: @CraigSmith That looks very wrong. Even if there is somehow an application called `wallpaper.wallpaperapp.app` in that directory, it would probably be an application bundle, not a binary executable. It's also unlikely that it would work correctly when run from launchd, outside a desktop session.

Comment: @CraigSmith You are right, that is my mistake. But still it is not working :(

Comment: What about @vadian's Answer?

Comment: @CraigSmith Better but not working still

Comment: By the way, in my own code, I've changed interval to 1 so I can know if it changed right away instead of actually waiting a hour.

Comment: What's the purpose of `KeepAlive` and `Nice` in this case just to run an AppleScript? And in which folder is the launchd file? You have also to consider access privileges since your script is in the local Library folder.

Comment: run `lanuchctl list`, it will give you a list of all launchd processes. Just before your process you should see a status code (most others will have a 0). Find that code and look it up, you will get much insight into any issues by checking that status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartCalendarInterval` runs the script at a specific time every day, in your case at 01:00 (1 am)

To run it every hour you have to write

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>3600</integer>
```

Comment: Still Further Progress.. Below is the updated code. Still not much luck.